# Can anyone suggest why this post has not reopened?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

The post [Approaches for generating synthetic survey data with dependent answers?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141285/approaches-for-generating-synthetic-survey-data-with-dependent-answers) closed for being too broad.

The post is now far less broad (Vass edited it extensively, I've since tidied it a little) -- indeed there are many far broader questions on site that remain open.

Closure should be a way to help people improve their questions. I think that's happened (I don't think it's a perfect question -- just an answerable one).

I don't think it's consistent for this post to stay closed as too broad, yet as far as I can see it remains on only one vote to reopen.

Can anyone who voted for it to remain closed clarify what's still too broad about it? What would it need to make it even more narrowly focused so that it's no longer overly broad?

Comment: For some reason, after you edited it seven hours ago it never showed up in the "Reopen" review queue.  This might be something for the SE team to address.

Comment: @whuber shouldn't it have been in the review queue from when Vass edited it before me?

Comment: The history shows it was closed by community voting on March 11. Three people voted not to re-open it between 21 and 13 hours ago. Your edit was logged 7 hours ago. After that, up to the point (a few minutes ago) when I re-opened the thread, there are no visible records of votes for or against reopening and the thread itself indicated there was only one reopen vote (presumably yours). I checked the Reopen review queue and found it empty. On this evidence I suspect that a thread that has been voted down for re-opening might not ever make it back into the Reopen queue, even after more editing.

Comment: Hmm. That does seem a worry. But I find the votes not to reopen on Vass' edit puzzling in any case - whatever its remaining flaws I don't fathom how it can have been regarded as still too broad.

Comment: I voted to leave closed. When I did so, which may be before the edits were finished, I thought the Q was 90% of the way there. I meant to leave a comment, but it appears I didn't.

Comment: @gung the fault was entirely mine. (If I'm going to edit, I need to remember to edit first, then vote to reopen.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All this question needed was a reopen vote. That would have kicked this question back into the reopen queue.

There was one reopen vote cast after Vass's edit, but it was cast *while the first reopen review was still happening*. So when the verdict of that review turned out to be "Leave Closed", that reopen vote's power to kick questions up to the queue was tragically stymied. But since the post was not reopened, that vote was never cleared, so the original reopen-voter couldn't re-use their vote.

Simple, right? (Has the word 'reopen' totally lost meaning for anyone else? Just me? Okay fine.)